# Aggregate Exception on client.ExecuteWithoutResults()

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I'm trying to create many ( in this case about 25000) nodes with one parameterized Cypher Create Request. While doing this after about 30 seconds a `System.AggregateException` is thrown.
I don't know how to avoid and how i can get around with it.

```
public void createFiles(File[] files)
{
    client.Cypher
          .Create("(file:FILE {newFiles})")
          .WithParam("newFiles", files)
          .ExecuteWithoutResults();
}
```

The `File[] files` is an object array with about 25.000 object each with 6 string properties.

I tried to split the array in smaller arrays (each 1000 objects) and foreach through them, but a `System.AggregateException` is thrown,too.

Exception like follows:

```
    System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Neo4jClient.GraphClient.SendHttpRequest(HttpRequestMessage request, String commandDescription, HttpStatusCode[] expectedStatusCodes) in ...Neo4jClient\
raphClient.cs:line 138
   at Neo4jClient.GraphClient.Neo4jClient.IRawGraphClient.ExecuteCypher(CypherQuery query) in ...\Neo4jClient\GraphClient.cs:line 843
   at Neo4jClient.Cypher.CypherFluentQuery.ExecuteWithoutResults() in ...\Neo4jClient\Cypher\CypherFluentQuery.cs:line 322
   at FileSystemSizeAnalyser.Database.createFolders(File[] files) in ...\FileSystemSiz
Analyser\Database.cs:line 65
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.<---
```

Any suggestion where to look and how to avoid this Exception? Furthermore, is there a way to resend the request till it succeed?

on Neo4jClient 1.0.0.656

Comment: What does the exception say?

Comment: [`AggregateException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception.aspx) is used to combine multiple separate exceptions (eg. from running things in parallel). You need to look at its `InnerExceptions` property (not the plural) to see the actual exceptions.

Comment: added Exception to question

Comment: Do you have any control over the `Timeout` option of your request?

Comment: Don't know how if it is possible

Comment: Looks like a timeout issue. What happens if you use HTTP POST directly to the transactional cypher endpoint? Which streams back and forth. I think this is just the client building up all the content and sending it over in one go. 25k nodes to create in one call shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Can you explain me how to try this? Is there any way to make the timout higher?